# Get the coordinate positions in UITextView which seems to work on bug behaviour

Tags: objective-c, uitextview

I just try to implement a custom UITextView allowing to move it anywhere by finger slide.

Created a custom UITextView subclass in order to get the coordinate positions of UITextView in real time. If the textView has one line you cannot get its positions properly. However you have three lines in textView you will be able to collect its positions correctly.

Here is my code snippets (within UITextView subclass)

```
- (void)awakeFromNib{
// touch detection enable
self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self];
firstTouchEventPoint = location;}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
// Parent View point
CGPoint mainViewPoint = super.self.frame.origin;
//NSLog(@"main x %f y %f", mainViewPoint.x, mainViewPoint.y);

// Single touch event
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self];

_diffPoint = CGPointMake(location.x - firstTouchEventPoint.x, location.y - firstTouchEventPoint.y);
CGRect rect = CGRectMake((mainViewPoint.x + _diffPoint.x),
                         (mainViewPoint.y + _diffPoint.y),
                         self.frame.size.width,
                         self.frame.size.height);
self.frame = rect;}
```

[image]
Is that the official bug in dodgy UITextView?